# Pitch detection and change java

Tags: java, audio, fft, pitch, javasound

I'm french so I'm sorry if you have trouble to understand some of my sentences.
Anyways, I saw in some topics that the pitch could be fetected thanks to the Fourier transform
but I didn't really understand how to implement it.
Moreover, I didn't find how to change the pitch of a wav file  and if possibl ,a mp3 file
I am listening to music using javaSound for the wav and JLayer for the mp3.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're just getting started with audio. Consider using [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/) or [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) to learn about the Fourier transform. See their respective signal processing packages. The reason I'm suggesting MATLAB or Octave is because it will help you learn faster than Java will. You need to learn about what you want to code before you actually code it. The book [DAFX](http://books.google.ca/books?id=h90HIV0uwVsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=DAFX&source=bl&ots=diCcKIwcfX&sig=OSyHQV59p1CAreIbPJRpAcTRP4c&hl=en&ei=p2EiTfLdCoa0lQeajNXiDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) would be a good place to start learning and it also includes sample MATLAB scripts for pitch shifting, and probably detection as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try those and I'm coming back to you